# insert input syntax is invalid for double precision type

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

Iam sending data from a form to php with ajax then insert into my table but get this error `insert input syntax is invalid for double precision type` when i try to insert lon and lat.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#form_interview", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $form = $(this);
    let data_Form = {
        lon:$("#lon").val(),
        lat:$("#lat").val(),
        geom:"point("+$("#lon").val()+" "+$("#lat").val()+")"
    }
    let url = "http://localhost:8077/know/validations/list.php?get=interview";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data_Form,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
    })
```

```
       $lon =$_POST['lon'];
        $lat =$_POST['lat'];
        $geom =$_POST['geom'];
        $set_interview = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO datos(lon,lat,geom)
                                                VALUES    (:lon,:lat,:geom)");

        $set_interview->bindParam(':lon',$lon,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $set_interview->bindParam(':lat',$lat,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $set_interview->bindParam(':geom',$geom,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $set_interview->execute();

        $return_array['is_login']=true;
        echo json_encode($return_array);
```

I looked for some information about floating numbers with PDO but i think i have to use `PARAM_STR` anyway

tried using `values(:lon::float8)` but it doesn't work

Error show on line 103, it refears to `$set_interview->execute();`

[image: error]

Comment: The error message will include the offending value. Please add that to the question.

Comment: just updated the question.

Comment: Looks like you got an empty string somewhere in your data.

Comment: sending console.log to `$("#lon").val()` i noticed its empty, just changed to `.text()` and now its working